# SQLite: Return the most recent 'n' rows per unique value of column 'y'

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  msg_id TEXT,
  thread_id TEXT,
  .
  .
  .
  date INTEGER 
)
```

I need to retrieve the most recent *n* `msg_id` per unique value of `thread_id`. Is there a way to do it using a single query or will I need to query the database to get the most recent distinct `thread_ids`, then query the database again PER unique `thread_id`? I recall reading somewhere that multiple database queries can get expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery.  For example, for `N = 5` :

```
select  *
from    YourTable yt1
where   5 <
        (
        select  count(*)
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt2.thread_id = yt1.thread_id
                and yt2.msg_id < yt1.thread_id
        )
```

This is not too fast, so you might be better of with multiple queries.

Comment: I don't even understand how your query works (I'm not an SQL expert, so it's my fault), so you're probably right in saying I'm better off sticking to multiple queries. Thank you for your response. I guess Occam's Razor.